# The "TypeScript.Tasks.FindConfigFiles" task could not be loaded from the assembly

Tags: asp.net-web-api, typescript, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

After updating the VS 2015 Community edition to Update 2 my ASP.NET Web API project fails to build under different environments with weird TypeScript error.

The project is just a plain Web API with no client scripts or whatsoever.

**Error details**

*The "TypeScript.Tasks.FindConfigFiles" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript\TypeScript.tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript\TypeScript.tasks.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.*

Comment: I had similar issue fixed by installing latest TS version. Also see [this bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4971#issuecomment-144184935)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have same problem, to resolve the problem I just uninstall older version of Typescript (installed with VS2013) and re-install newer version (with VS2015).